# Firebase data validation with programmatically generated key created by Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm doing a simple book manager app with React and Firebase. The user can enter the book's author, title and rating, and I'm trying to validate the input.

Data is structured as follows:

```js
"books" : {
    "-LSon2JjuqUWb6tXV-EA" : {
      "author" : "Stephen King",
      "rating" : "5",
      "title" : "\"Misery\""
    },
    "-LSp33lP1b5W2XOXyEmI" : {
      "author" : "Stephen King",
      "rating" : "10",
      "title" : "\"Cujo\""
    }
}
```

Each key is programmatically generated by Firebase when push method is called.
Now, I'd like to validate the users' input, but the key seems to raise an issue. How should I refer to it in the statements? Or maybe there's a completely different reason for my rules not working? If I omit the generated key and refer to the author/title/rating directly in the "books" object, I can add data which don't meet the conditions I've stated.

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true",
      "books" : {
        "???" : {
          "author" : {
            ".validate" : "newData.isString() && newData.val() > 0"
          },
          "title" : {
            ".validate" : "newData.isString() && newData.val() > 0"
          },
          "rating" : {
            ".validate" : "newData.isNumber()"
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I would be grateful for any tips.

[Link to the repo of my project](https://github.com/MagdaFronczyk/book-manager)

Comment: You've included pictures of the rules and JSON tree in your question. Please replace these with the actual rules and JSON as text. The latter you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the rules and JSON as text makes them searchable, allows us to easily use them to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: It would also be good if you indicate what doesn't work about your rules. If it's related to code that you tried, show the minimal code that reproduces the problem with these rules and explain what doesn't work about it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your advice and for making my post more legible. I edited it according to your suggestions. I hope the changes I made will help.

Comment: Again: make sure that all textual content is in the post as text. There is no need for any screenshots here. Right now if I'd want to answer, I'd have to retype a large part of your rules. While some folks may, it is dumb handy work for them and can be prevented if you provide all text and use the Stack Overflow formatting tools to make it look good.

Answer (score 0):

You should first go to the rules simulator test your rules, that's on    the right side of your rules.

In the simulation type select SET.

In the zone write /books/{newkey} In the the JSON area do write :

{
"authors":"author data"
}

Repeat this for each of the fields that are underneath the newkey (your push generated key) node.

This will at least tell you which of the rules don't work and if you click on details you will be able to know why.

Also i would add, how do you come up with data like author:"stephen , i mean woithout the last quotation mark?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to your firebase push key as e.g. "$bookId" and then can use it in rules, if needed.

Example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "rooms": {
      // this rule applies to any child of /rooms/, the key for each room id
      // is stored inside $room_id variable for reference
      "$room_id": {
        "topic": {
          // the room's topic can be changed if the room id has "public" in it
          ".write": "$room_id.contains('public')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments